# Iterate the json array to get a value only once jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
[{
    "id": "2015-07-002",
    "class": "7",
    "nature": "1",
    "resolution": "res1",
    "mstatus": "1",
    "cstatus": null,
    "astatus": null
}, {
    "id": "2015-07-002",
    "class": "7",
    "nature": "1",
    "resolution": "res1",
    "mstatus": "2",
    "cstatus": null,
    "astatus": null
}]
```

This is my sample json object (it can have so many values but the format is like this)how can i iterate this sample to get the value of nature only once per id i wanted to have a counter in which i want to count how many nature with `value 1` and with  `value 0` (the only value of nature is `1` and `0`) for every `id`. The `id` with be the unique identifying body.

What i want is to be able to count the nature for every id example out put will be

`ID:2015-07-002
 Nature0:0
 Nature1:1`

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: wait it is a bit long i am doing a fiddle now

Comment: ok no problem, I can help you but I don't want to make your homework :) I'm working right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the id in an array then check that array if you are iterating the array.

```
var nature = [];

var data=[{
    "id": "2015-07-002",
    "class": "7",
    "nature": "1",
    "resolution": "res1",
    "mstatus": "1",
    "cstatus": null,
    "astatus": null
}, {
    "id": "2015-07-002",
    "class": "7",
    "nature": "1",
    "resolution": "res1",
    "mstatus": "2",
    "cstatus": null,
    "astatus": null
}];

var nature0 = 0;
var nature1 = 0;
$.each(data, function(index , value){
if ($.inArray(value.id, nature) == -1) {
 nature.push(value.id);
if(value.nature == '0'){
nature0++;
console.log(nature0);
}else if(value.nature == '1'){
nature1++;

console.log(nature1);
}


}
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/mfjz1o40/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Make an object whose keys are the id's, and the value is an object with a counter for zeroes and ones.

Also, `$(data).each()` is used for iterating over collections of jQuery elements. To iterate over an array, use `$.each()`.

```
var counters = {}
$.each(data, function() {
    var id = this.id;
    if (!counters[id]) {
        counters[id] = {"0" : 0, "1", 0};
    }
    counters[id][this.nature]++;
}
for (id in counters) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log('  Nature0 ' + counters[id]['0']);
    console.log('  Nature1 ' + counters[id]['1']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j8whdht8/3/)

**CODE**

```
var data=[{
    "id": "2015-07-002",
    "class": "7",
    "nature": "1",
    "resolution": "res1",
    "mstatus": "1",
    "cstatus": null,
    "astatus": null
}, {
    "id": "2015-07-002",
    "class": "7",
    "nature": "1",
    "resolution": "res1",
    "mstatus": "2",
    "cstatus": null,
    "astatus": null
}];

$(":button").click(function(){
    var zeros=0;
    var ones=0;
    $(data).each(function(i,v){
        if($(this)[0].nature==0)
        {
            zeros++;
        }
        if($(this)[0].nature==1)
        {
            ones++;
        }
    });
    alert("ZEROS:"+zeros+"\r\nONES:"+ones);
});
```